# Eclipse JCOP- rebuilding project?

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I am using jcop tool plugin with eclipse and my atr is:-

```
--Opening terminal
<div class="jive-quote"> /card -a a000000003000000 -c com.ibm.jc.CardManager</div>
--Waiting for card...
ATR=3B E9 00 00 81 31 FE 45 4A 43 4F 50 34 31 56 32    ;....1.EJCOP41V2
    32 A7                                              2.
```

everything is fine with sample applet { it contain a empty process () or gives 90 00 for select applet apdu }

I am using eclipse ide and jcop plugin, basically my problem is to building project when any changes occoured, initially when i start a new project with steps like:-
1- java card project

2-java applet

3-package id

4-applet id

5-basic template of applet
...

N- finish
ok

then when screen open, at the left side i saw cap file propery window ,and automatically there are cap file in bin folder.

It means jcop tool used converter to make .cap file, but when i add some lines according to my requirment,
I am unable to build it again or unable to get a new cap file. 
May be i need to set some build path , but first time it automatically build so 
  it also
 indicate that there are no need to set the build path. I am confused in this area.
Is i need to reference the path of converter.jar { jcdk 2.2.1 }? or jcop plugin also have the required jar for converting .class to .cap , inside it. how i rebuild it and make a new fresh .cap file.

some jar file which i paste in plugin folder of eclipse are:-

```
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.demopack_1.0.2.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.perftest_1.0.2.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.signlite_1.0.2.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.targetpack.gemplus_1.0.0.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse.targetpack_1.0.3.3.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse_1.0.3.3.jar
com.ibm.bluez.jcop.eclipse_3.1.1.a.jar
```

before i was using JCDE plugin for simulation process but here i did not use JCDE, I have only eclipse + jcop plugin

I tried to tell you, what is my problem, If you still have any doubt , Let me know.

Waiting for your reply and thanks for your time ............

Answer (score 1):

If your Java classes compiled correctly then the build path should be OK. It's more likely that the JCOP converter (it's included as a build step in the project) fails. This could be because there are some Java Card restrictions that have been broken. Unfortunately, the JCOP converter *can* fail silently. Common reasons are: the use of integers within expressions/comparisions and the use of byte code (method calls, field access) within constants (`static final` fields).

If you cannot figure it out, try to compile and convert using the official Java Card API and converter (you can add additional libs to the official converter in the form of `.ext` files and of course `.jars` or classes). It will probably catch more errors, including the ones above.

Comment: _The JCOP converter can fail silently._ Does this mean that, sometimes when I change my program, the JCOP doesn't update the _.cap_ file? (In cases that the changes that I done are OK and error-less)

Comment: @Abraham Usually it seems that it may not generate it at all, especially if the delete of the previous folder structure failed. Fortunately I haven't seen an error where the old cap file persisted, but if you have an important release I would check the file dates just to be sure. Personally I have/had a release build environment separate from Eclipse, but I guess that is a luxury that most people don't have.

Comment: Is that release build environment shareable?

Comment: @Abraham Heh, no. There are some ant tasks in the JC environment, so it should be *relatively* easy to create one of your own. Note that the ant tasks are not (well) maintained though.

Comment: OK. Unfortunately I don't have any idea what is ANT Task mean! I just know it is something related to Apache and xml files!

Comment: Ant build files are XML files that describe *what* needs to be build. The ant tasks are the parts that do the building. There is for instance an ant task for the cap file converter in the Java Card (offcard) API. Ant is more or less the Java version of `make`.

Comment: Thanks. Where is this .xml files when I use JCDE plugin to convert my Java card applets? Am I need to change it in any situation? What I must know about it?

Answer (score 0):

Initially i was unable to getting the eclipse and JCOP concept, but now i do.
 now I am able to build the project or eclipse is building it automatically !!!!  I faced this problem b'se i am a newbie in java card. but now things going good to me.

**I want to share my getting  here:--**

**My dout was**-  Is jcop intially have all the Jar's , converter which is required to create a cap file????
  **My ans is**- Yes, EVERYTHING IT HAVE INSIDE.
you just get **eclipse ide** and get **jcop plugin**, and **paste jcop plugin jar's** inside the plugin folder of ecipse and **START** ECLIPS AGAIN.

NOW EVERYTHING IS SET FOR YOU,
**NO** REQUIREMENT OF JCDE-java card development envoirnment
   **no** requirement of jcdk- java card development kit ,
  **no** requirement of set any build path in eclipse.
just make your applet , and run with jcop tool.
 **ECIPSE AUTOMATICALLY BUILD OPTION WILL CREATE A FRESH .CAP FILE WHENEVER U MADE A NEW CHANGES**
cheers!!!

Comment: Ah, well, glad you got it working daniel. Be warned that JCOP builds may fail silently sometimes, if you are unsure, check the date of the .cap files, and see my answer above. The JCOP tools are *much* easier to use than most card development environments out there, even though they have some rather annoying quirks. You can accept your own answer after a while.

Answer (score 0):

No need JCDE. After you change the code, just save it and then go to run configuration menu to install the applet. Then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

i think this would be very useful for you to start building the java card development environment.
http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1755905/